# How to open an item from an API list in a new page with PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I have a code that looks in an API and displays the results in a table. As follows.

```
<?php
$apikey = "api_key=my_api_key";
$url = "http://api.link.com/property?" . implode("&", array($apikey));

$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, TRUE));
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($result->properties as $row) { 
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->type;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
        <td><a href="api-item.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->title; ?></a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to open each of the items in a new page, where all the options for each unique id are displayed.

```html
<?php //api-item.php
$post_id = $_GET['id'];
$apikey = "api_key=my_api&id=".$post_id;
$url = "http://api.link.com/property?" . implode("&", array($apikey));

$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, TRUE));

    foreach ($result->properties as $row) { 
?>
    <strong><?php echo $row->title; ?></strong><br><br>
    <strong>DESCRIPTION</strong><br>
    <?php echo $row->description; ?>

    <strong>CONSIDERATIONS</strong><br>
    <?php echo $row->considerations; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks everyone! The problem was solved!

Comment: What's the link to the new page? Add somewhere a link with target='_blank'...

Comment: You can add  a view button in the last column of your table, or an anchor tag to your id/name, and onclick of that, using target="_blank" property you can redirect it to new tab

Comment: If the issue is in `api-item.php` please show that code not the index

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> (User has edited his question with the portion of code to link the
>   $row->action td present in this answer).

I guess you are using the item id to identify each page, so you can try the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="theItemPage.php?id=<?php echo $row->id;?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row->id;?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->type;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->action;?></td>
</tr>
```

Of course you can move the  tag anywhere you need (if you prefer users to click on the name, for example).

> Given your edits, this is the code a little bit refactored you should
>   use:

```
<?php //api-item.php
    $post_id = $_GET['id'];
    $apikey = "api_key=my_api&id=".$post_id;
    $url = "http://api.link.com/property?" . implode("&", array($apikey));

    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, TRUE));

    // You don't need to re-assign $post_id, you already did it on the top of the page.
    $output = "";
    foreach ($result->properties as $row) {

        $output .= "<strong>".$row->title."</strong><br><br>";
        $output .= "<strong>DESCRIPTION</strong><br>".$row->description."<br><br>";
        $output .= "<strong>CONSIDERATIONS</strong><br>$row->considerations;
    }
    echo $output;
```

1. You don't need to re-declare $post_id inside the for loop, the ID value passed as parameter is only one per page hit.
2. Be careful when you concatenate the $post_id to the api string on the top of the page, check the refactored code.

Comment: Thanks! I can make it open on another page. What I need is to see only the options of the ID selected on the new page.

Comment: Did you try anything to display data in the new page? I can't write an entire framework on your behalf :)

Comment: Yes, I tried a few things, but nothing really worked. So I'm here, trying to get some help for the page //api-item.php

Comment: You should update your question with the code you tried. Or almost with the code you use to populate the $result array.

Comment: OK, now I get a blank page, but the ID is passed in the correct way.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the refactored code you should use. Note that  you should assign the id parameter outside the foreach loop. Please set this answer as the correct one if you found it useful.